# Automatically Add New Tags to Sub-menu

Tags: menus, tags, sub-menu

Been searching for any related plugins or info. about this case but didn't find anything relevant or working.

I need every new tag that is added to a post automatically appear in a menu as a sub-menu item.

Something like you can make pages automatically appear in a menu.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Plugin recommendations are not allowed, but there's a awesome plugin that can help you with that -> JC Submenu

Comment: Thank you, gdaniel. But due to my custom menu and walker it doesn't display it as it should... 
All in all, this is a good plugin and precisely the solution which I was looking for.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue with your walker is... but when I first used the plugin, I saw no changes because of my custom walker, then I found out that they have a filter to make it work with a custom walker

// disable jc submenu custom walker
add_filter('jcs/enable_public_walker', 'jc_disable_public_walker');
function jc_disable_public_walker($default){
    return false;
}

Comment: @gdaniel, that's amazing! It works well now. Just what I needed. Thank you very much! :))

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is what you want.
I test and works very fine.

[JC Submenu](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/jc-submenu/)
Por James Collings

Look the printscreen for understand. In this case the effect was: show all tags as menu item

[image]